# give context to page without render

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to make a help section for my team. I have a form that the person that needs help will fill out, then that data will go to a page only my team my can view to see which one of us will tackle the problem. But, I am having trouble rendering the context of the form to the help page my team can view. right now I am using render(), but when the user clicks submit he/she gets redirected to the page only my team should be able to see. and the data doesn't stay on the page when it is reloaded.

here is the views.py

```
def help_form(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = HelpForm(request.POST)

    # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            name = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
            room_number = form.cleaned_data['room_number']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            when = form.cleaned_data['when']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']

            context = {
                'name': name,
                'room_number': room_number,
                'email': email,
                'when': when,
                'subject': subject,
                'description': description,
            }

            # redirect to a new URL: 
            return render(request, 'website/asked_questions.html', context)


    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = HelpForm()

    return render(request, 'website/help_form.html', {'form':form})
```

if you need to see forms.py or my template let me know, i feel like I am just missing a type of render method. Thanks Guys!!

Comment: You'll need to save the data in your database so that your team can view the submitted form

Comment: ok, any suggestions to the easiest way to do that

Comment: 1) Create a model to save the submitted data 2) Use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) and `.save()` the form on a successful submission (the current view should just redirect to a thank you page) 3) Create a view that can only be accessed by your team for viewing those submitted objects